# Donut Chart in Salesforce

Tags: charts, salesforce, donut

Hi guys I need your help/advice.

I need to create a donut chart where I will be able to show the amount of 5 different fields (all currency fields in the opportunity object), so that in the donut chart will appear the percentage of amount of each of the 5 fields. Is there a way to make that possible?

As it seems that the donut chart will show you values of only one field.